# EF Core 3.1 PostgreSQL LEAD window function

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-core-3.1

We are using .NET Core 3.1, [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.9) and [Npgsql 4.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/4.1.9). We have the following simple `TestExecution` scaffolded class:

```cs
[Table("test_execution", Schema = "test")]
public partial class TestExecution
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("test_result")]
    public string TestResult { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Data in the PostgreSQL database looks like this:

| **id** | **test_result** | **name** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OK | test 1 |
| 2 | OK | test 2 |
| 3 | ERROR | test 3 |
| 4 | ERROR | test 4 |
| 5 | OK | test 5 |
| 6 | OK | test 6 |
| 7 | WARNING | test 7 |

We would like to return rows with the smallest `id` for the sequence of the same consecutive `test_result` values. Our expected output is:

| **id** | **test_result** | **name** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | WARNING | test 7 |
| 5 | OK | test 5 |
| 3 | ERROR | test 3 |
| 1 | OK | test 1 |

This can be achieved with the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
    id, 
    test_result, 
    name
FROM (
    SELECT
        id, 
        test_result, 
        name,
        LEAD(test_result) OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS next_result
    FROM fit.test_execution
    ) s
WHERE
    test_result is distinct from next_result;
```

How can we produce this SQL query by EF Core 3.1 and Linq without writing any raw SQL?

Comment: You can use [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) and window functions usage [Window functions](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Window-Functions-(Analytic-Functions).html). Install version 3.x.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv What I don't like about this library is that it **completely** [replaces](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore/issues/207#issuecomment-981860837) EF Core LINQ translator. Do there exist any as-lightweight-as-possible alternatives which support EF Core 3.1?

Comment: You can don't like it but `linq2db` translator is a way better. You have to search by yourself for other alternatives but I don't think someone still supports EF Core 3.x

Comment: And actually it replaces LINQ Translator only for particular query. You can control it.

Comment: Do you have any examples on how to enable `linq2db` only for a particular query?

Answer (score 1):

EF Core doesn't currently support window functions - that's tracked by [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12747).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) and window functions usage [Window functions](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Window-Functions-(Analytic-Functions).html). Install version 3.x. (note that I'm one of the creators)

```cs
var windowedQuery = 
    from te in context.test_execution
    select new 
    {
        te.id,
        te.test_result,
        te.name,
        next_result = Sql.Ext.Lead(te.test_result)
            .Over()
            .OrderByDesc(te.id)
            .ToValue()
    };

var query = 
    from w in windowedQuery
    where w.test_result.IsDistinctFrom(w.next_result)
    select new
    {
        w.id,
        w.test_result,
        w.name
    };

var result = await query.ToListAsyncLinqToDB(); // execute query via LINQ to DB
```